# The relation between .load and .ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading a part of a page into another page using the `.load` function in jQuery

```
$("#loadingDockShotPg").load("include/shot_comments.php?id="+get['id']);
```

In my file that's being loaded into the div with the id "loadingDockShotPg" there are elements in there in which I would like to be effected by my jQuery commands.

The HTML that's being placed into another page using `.load`

```
 <textarea id='newNoteTextarea' class='width100 hidden' placement='Write a comment...'></textarea>
```

The jQuery that's placed in the parent file that the HTML above is being placed in

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[placement], textarea[placement]").each(function(){
        var orAttr = $(this).attr("placement");

        $(this).val(orAttr);

        $(this).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val() == orAttr)
            {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        });
        $(this).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val() == "")
            {
                $(this).val(orAttr);
            }
        });
        });
    });
```

The problem is that my textarea isn't being affected by the jQuery that's supposed to put the placement attribute in the textarea's value. What do I have to do in order to have this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.load()` is a "live function". You are adding content to the DOM after it has been loaded. Your `.each()` function have already been executed before your content is added with the `.load()`. To fix this you can run your `.each()` function when `.load()` is complete as a callback.

This is how I should have done it:

```
$(function(){
    var inputElements = $("input[placement], textarea[placement]");

    function setInputValue() {
        var self = $(this),
            orAttr = self.attr("placement");

        self
            .val(orAttr)
            .focus(function(){
                if(self.val() == orAttr)
                {
                self.val("");
                }
            })
            .blur(function(){
                if(self.val() == "")
                {
                self.val(orAttr);
                }
            });
    }

    inputElements.each(setInputValue);

    $("#loadingDockShotPg").load("include/shot_comments.php?id="+get['id'], function(){
        inputElements = $("input[placement], textarea[placement]");
        inputElements.each(setInputValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: Question: is `$(function(){});` just like `$(document).ready(function(){});`?

Comment: @Majed As far as I know, it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using `.live()`, (which is technically depreciated) or `.on()` to attach/bind to events on selected elements when using `.load()`

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: The links will contain examples, however you would change your code thus: $(this).live("focus", function()....